# Java Client with ElasticSearch SearchQuery if the value of field is not empty

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I developed a java Client to interrogate with elasticsearch.

I want to pass in my method a java bean (with many attributes) as a parameter, and I want also that my query apply search just on field that are not empty

I used it this way in java but I'm wanting to do it well (with best practices) to replace `IF`.

If there is any solution from elasticsearch or java client for elasticsearch, please let me know.

```
public void chercherParplusisuersCrieres(EsClient esClient) {
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", esClient.getMotCle()));
    if (!esClient.getComplementAdresse().isEmpty()) {
        boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Complement_adresse", esClient.getComplementAdresse()));
    }
    if (!esClient.getNom().isEmpty()) {
        boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Nom", esClient.getNom()));
    }
    if (!esClient.getPrenom().isEmpty()) {
        boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Prenom", esClient.getPrenom()));
    }
    if (!esClient.getLibelleQuartier().isEmpty()) {
        boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("Libille_quartier", esClient.getLibelleQuartier()));
    }
    SearchRequestBuilder builder = this.client.prepareSearch("index").setTypes("index_type")
            .setQuery(boolQuery);
    System.out.println(builder);
    SearchResponse response = builder.get();
    List<EsClient> esClientList = new ArrayList<EsClient>();
    List<String> listColumns = Arrays.asList("Complement_adresse", "Nom", "Prenom", "Libille_quartier",
            "Date_operation");
    // get all Hits of response
    SearchHits searchHits = response.getHits();

    // searchHits.getHits() instead of searchHits.getTotalHist() beacause eclipse
    // support just 10 results
    for (int i = 0; i < searchHits.getHits().length - 1; i++) {
        esClient = new EsClient();
        esClient.setComplementAdresse((String) searchHits.getAt(i).getSourceAsMap().get(listColumns.get(0)));
        esClient.setNom((String) searchHits.getAt(i).getSourceAsMap().get(listColumns.get(1)));
        esClient.setLibelleQuartier((String) searchHits.getAt(i).getSourceAsMap().get(listColumns.get(2)));

        esClientList.add(esClient);
    }
    System.out.println(esClientList);

}
```